# Recursion for BSTs

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

What's the difference between these two recursive codes? The purpose is to flip the BST (every right and left subtree mirrored), one version does flips while going down, while the other waits until it gets to the bottom and then flips. So is there any difference between having part 2 before part 1 other than the order in which the flips happen?

```
private void mirror(Node node) { 

  if (node == null) return;

1____________________________
  // do the subtrees 
 mirror(node.left); 
    mirror(node.right);
2_________________________________
  // duplicate this node to its left 
     Node temp = node.left; 
    node.left = node.right; 
    node.right = temp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

suppose there is a tree like

```
        1
     2     3
   4   5  
 6
```

if you call part 2 before part 1 then first 2 will be swapped with 3, 4 with 5 and 6 with NULL(the right child of 4)
but if you call part 2 after part 1 then first 6 will be swapped with NULL,then 4 with 5, then 2 with 3.
It means that there is only the difference in the order(sequence) in which they are creating the mirror image.